# How to redirect streamed data to date based files?

Tags: bash

I have a process that is streaming data (ssh connection) and I do want to redirect its output to a filename that based on the current date.

The problem is that I do want to "rotate" the file at midnight so I would end-up with one file for each day of stream-logging.

Can I do this only in bash? How?

Ideally the rotation should happen without breaking newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by "without breaking newlines" ?

Comment: @janos If you receive one line at 23:59:59 you may want to get it written to the current day log and start the new day of logging on the next line instead of having single line spread into two files.

Comment: So you don't want to break *lines*. Does this also mean that we can read from the stream line by line? (as opposed to reading byte by byte)

Comment: While not sure yet but lets assume that it has line buffering enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could read `stdin` line by line, and append to a file, with the name depending on the date at the time the line was read.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    log=log.$(date +%F)
    echo "$line" >> "$log"
done
```